# Markdown in embeds discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, markdown, embed

I wanna bold some text in my embed. I searched in google for discord's markdown and tried using `**` , but it didn't work. Here is a hastebin with my embed code: https://hastebin.com/gidusegutu.js .
In Discord it just appears like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make embed title bold because it is **already** bold! Also I recommend you to use [`.setTitle`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTitle) instead of [`.setAuthor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setAuthor) if you want to add emojis and markdown to your embed [`title`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=title).